# detect two element overlap point

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any method to detect two element overlap point?

For example, refer the below code that I used.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .s1, .s2 {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .s1 {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .s2 {
      background-color: aquamarine;
    }
    .s1 p {
      position: fixed;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="s1">
    <p class="p">TEST</p>
  </div>
  <div class="s2">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Very simple code. Just two `<div>` and one `<p>` tag.

I set `position: fixed` to `<p>` tag because made it always positioned center of screen.

So, now is the point what I want to do.

Is there any way to detect `<p>` and `.s2` meet point?

When `<p>` meet the `.s2`, I want to change it's color.

[image]

(I mean this point)

Any solution here?

I want to make with pure html/css/js. But is there any library related it, it doesn't matter.

Thanks.

Comment: Dynamic changes needs JS

Comment: @rv7 It's ok also use js.

Comment: Have you tried position and offset. Consider this snippen   $('.post-signature.owner').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() paste in this stackoverflow's console. You can create similar logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Event Listeners`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to do this.

```js
window.onload = function() {  
  let p = document.querySelector('.s1 p');
  let s2 = document.querySelector('.s2');

  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    let coordP = p.getBoundingClientRect();
    let coordS2 = s2.getBoundingClientRect();

    if(coordP.bottom > coordS2.top) {
      p.style.color = 'yellow';
    }
    else p.style.color = 'black';
  });
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .s1, .s2 {
      height: 100vh;
    }
    .s1 {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
    .s2 {
      background-color: aqua;
      border: 1px solid aqua;
    }
    .s1 p {
      position: fixed;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="s1">
    <p class="p">TEST</p>
  </div>
  <div class="s2">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works properly in stackoverflow snippet. But in my local, it throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null at window.addEventListener` errors.

Comment: @Hide I updated my answer. I used `window.onload` to check that the contents has been loaded so that `p` should have a value

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!